# ionic3 & angular4 build :Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJava'

Tags: angular, cordova, plugins, ionic3

In the use of the cordova camera plug-in, when I build the project,it reported the following mistakes:

[image]

Comment: Remove `node_modules` folder and try that again.

Comment: Also in the future, post the text of exceptions rather then screenshot. this makes your issue easier to find for people who will have same problem in the future

Comment: Remove node_modules doesn't help.

Comment: OK then try after removing `platforms` folder.

Comment: It doesn't helpe either,and the error turns as follows:
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: ...
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project.

Comment: Which `CLI` cmd you used?

Comment: tabs............

Comment: I was wondering if it would be a mistake for gradle not to compile cordva's camera plug-in.