# cordova build Android error:Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJava'

Tags: cordova-plugins, ionic3

I got error when I build the Android project,after I added cordova Camera plugin,can anybody give me a hand,thanks a lot.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

D:\Angular4\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                    ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "D:\Angular4\myApp\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b D:\Angular4\myApp\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"

Command finished with error code 1: cmd /s /c "D:\Angular4\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat"
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
D:\Angular4\myApp\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\camera\CordovaUri.java:78: ����: �Ҳ�������
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                                                       ^
  ����:   ���� M
  λ��: �� VERSION_CODES
ע: D:\Angular4\myApp\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\splashscreen\SplashScreen.javaʹ�û����ѹ�ʱ�� API��
ע: �й���ϸ��Ϣ, ��ʹ�� -Xlint:deprecation ���±��롣
1 ������
```

Comment: It seems you're spamming here.Please don't do that.If you have new content please add it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45911506/ionic3-angular4-build-execution-failed-for-task-compiledebugjava

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ionic3 & angular4 build :Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJava'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45911506/ionic3-angular4-build-execution-failed-for-task-compiledebugjava)